# Unapprovable RejectedAccessException when using Tuple in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I tried to use Tuple in a Jenkinsfile.

The line I wrote is `def tupleTest = new Tuple('test', 'test2')`.

However, Jenkins did not accept this line and keep writing the following error to the console output:

> No such constructor found: new groovy.lang.Tuple java.lang.String java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
>
> ...
>
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such constructor found: new groovy.lang.Tuple java.lang.Integer java.lang.String
>
> ...

When I visited the "Script Approval" configuration I could not see any scripts that pend approval.

Following [this](https://www.laurivan.com/fix-missing-in-process-script-approval-in-jenkins/) link, I tried to install and enable the "[Permissive Security](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin)" plugin, but it did not help either - The error was the same.

I even tried to manually add the problematic signature to the `scriptApproval.xml` file. After I added it, I was able to see it in the list of approved signatures, but the error still remained.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less a problem caused by `groovy.lang.Tuple` constructor + Jenkins sandbox Groovy mode. If you take a look at the constructor of this class you will see [something like this](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_12/src/main/groovy/lang/Tuple.java#L35-L38):

```java
package groovy.lang;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tuple extends AbstractList {
    private final Object[] contents;
    private int hashCode;

    public Tuple(Object[] contents) {
        if (contents == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    //....
}
```

Groovy sandbox mode *(enabled by default for all Jenkins pipelines)* ensures that every invocation passes script approval check. It's not foolproof, and when it sees `new Tuple('a','b')` it thinks that the user is looking for a constructor that matches exactly two parameters of type `String`. And because such constructor does not exists, it throws this exception. However, there are two simple workarounds to this problem.

### Use `groovy.lang.Tuple2` instead

If your tuple is a pair, then use `groovy.lang.Tuple2` instead. The good news about this class is that it provides a constructor [that supports two generic types](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_12/src/main/groovy/lang/Tuple2.java#L25-L27), so it will work in your case.

### Use exact `Object[]` constructor

Alternatively, you can use the exact constructor, e.g

```
def tuple = new Tuple(["test","test2"] as Object[])
```

Both options require script approval before you can use them (however, in this case both constructors appear in the in-process script approval page).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue trying to use tuple on jenkins so I found out that I can simply use a list literal instead:

```
def tuple = ["test1", "test2"]
```

which is equivalent to

```
def (a, b) = ["test1", "test2"]
```

So now, instead of returning a tuple, I am returning a list in my method

```
def myMethod(...) {
    ...
    return ["test 1", "test 2"]
}

...

def (a, b) = myMethod(...)
```

Comment: this is the way better answer or lets say relevant?!?
above is  a bit TL; DR; but I read it anyways and didnt want to go there.